# jBPM web based approval system

Tags: persistence, jbpm

I am working in web based approval system where:

1. User select folder and ask for approval to a approver
2. Approver log in and found pending approval list and upon checking few criteria approve or reject the approval request
3. Corresponding  mail will be fired to user
4. Every state will be stored in db

Can anyone help me with web based jBPM sample project.

I have checked few jBPM projects in github but not clear about persistance(saving the state)and human task,how they work.

Any sample project or link please share

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these articles:

- http://mswiderski.blogspot.com/2016/10/case-management-jbpm-v7-part-1.html
- http://mswiderski.blogspot.com/2016/10/case-management-jbpm-v7-part-2-working.html
- http://mswiderski.blogspot.com/2016/10/case-management-jbpm-v7-part-3-dynamic.html

And here is using showcase case mgmt UI
http://mswiderski.blogspot.com/2017/04/case-management-application-in-workbench.html

From my point of view, it does have approval system.

Comment: Hi hnandarusdy ..thanks for the links. But I am using eclipse jbpm plugin to develop my system. I am wondering if a user submit request  for approval and it will start the process and he logs out. Then if the approver logs in how the human task related to the apprver be tracked by the system and the approver start working on it. We will use persistance but what if multiple user submit approve req to multiple approver. How the whole thing will be tracked and mamged. Shd I create 2 workflow for user and approver?

Comment: Hi hnandarusdy thanks for the links. But I am usinh eclipse  jbpm plugin for my application . I have 2 qn
1. If a user submit approval req then the process will be started,likewise suppose multiple user submit req,in that case multiple instance of the process will be created and how they wil be saved?
2. Now wen the approver will login how he will proceed with the approver human task assigned to him of the same process or shd I design separate related workflow/process/bmpn file?